# Is it possible to change the application name that appears in the icon of iOS Apps?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

When you install the application in iOs, IPad for example, there is an icon and a name, the name by default is the same of your app name.

Is it possible to change this name?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the name in either Xcode or Worklight, however it would be of best practice to change it in Worklight so that it will propagate to all used environments in your Worklight project. It will also prevent you from accidentally "going back" in the given name if you ever re-build your project in Eclipse prior to moving to Xcode (the Xcode project will be overwritten).

In your Worklight project, open application-descriptor.xml and change the value of the `displayName` element.

If you choose to do so in Xcode, go to info.plist located in the resources folder and change the `Bundle Display Name`.

Comment: Is there somewhere else I need to change the name because only changing the application descriptor doesn't seem to change the name under the icon?

Comment: Looks like a bug sneaked in here. I will open a defect about this, thanks. In Android you can navigate to your android\native\res\values\strings.xml and change the value for <string name="app_name">test</string> . In iOS you will need to navigate to the native\projectNameAppNameIphone-Info.plist file and change the BundleDisplayName value. And then re-build the application.